# Stuck in boot-loop (Broken partition / filesystem?)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, recovery-mode, boot-loop, twrp, partitions

My Samsung S3 (rooted, running LineageOS) is "soft-bricked":

- Stuck in Boot-loop with Samsung Logo
- I can still boot into 'ODIN' download mode
- I can still boot into 'TWRP' recovery mode

On launch, the TWRP logs show that something is gravely wrong with the file-system:

```
Failed to mount '/cache' (Invalid argument)
E:primary block device '/dev/block/mmcblk0p12' for mount point '/data' is not present!
Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument)
Unable to recreate /data/media folder
Updating partition details...
Failed to mount '/efs' (Invalid argument)
Failed to mount '/cache' (Invalid argument)
Failed to mount '/system' (Invalid argument)
Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument)
Failed to mount '/preload' (Invalid argument)
...done
Unable to mount storage
Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument)
Fill SELinux support is present.
Unable to mount /data/media/TWRP/.twrps
MTP Enabled
```

I've re-flashed the TWRP image, but the problem persists.

I've even tried an advanced-wipe of EVERYTHING, but that fails, too:

```
Unable to wipe Cache.
Unable to wipe /cache.
Updating partition details...
Failed to mount '/efs' (Invalid argument)
Failed to mount '/cache' (Invalid argument)
Failed to mount '/system' (Invalid argument)
Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument)
Failed to mount '/preload' (Invalid argument)
...done
Unable to mount storage
```

For some reason I can't mount ANYTHING.

I can connect over ADB, so I tried flashing a custom ROM:

```
Installing zip file '/sdcard/lineage-14.1..zip'
...
could not detect filesystem for /dev/block/mmcblk0p9, assuming ext4
mount: failed to mount /dev/block/mmcblk0p9 at /
system: No such file or directory
unmount of system/ failed: no such volume

could not detect filesystem for /dev/block/mmcblk0p12, assuming f2fs
mount: failed to mount /dev/block/mmcblk0p12 at /
data: No such file or directory
unmount of data/ failed: no such volume

Patching system image unconditionally...
E1001: Failed to update system image.
Updater process ended with ERROR: 7

Error installing zip file '/sdcard/lineage-14.1..zip'
```

Do I need to put my phone in the bin?

(P.s. Apologies if there are typos in the above logs, they are manually typed as `adb logcat` didn't work..!)

Answer (score 0):

Try flashing Stock ROM via ODIN as it won't require recovery and will generate proper system, recovery and other partitions. After that, as for errors, I suggest you to try flashing a old version of recovery ( In case you are flashing latest).

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but even with the stock recovery I saw the same errors.